# Send an SMS without the delivery report

Tags: android, sms, report

I used this good tutorial http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android for sending SMS in my android app.

If I do not want the provider to send me the delivery report when sending a sms, is it enough to set the delivery intent to NULL?

Like instead of:

```
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

use

```
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, NULL);
```

or is there an additional setting to prevent SMS delivery reports?

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting an SMS (or a System-Message) from your Provider, which tells you that the SMS was successfully send? If so, you might activated some "alert when successfully send" thing in your SMS app.

Otherwise yes, if you don't want the Intent, just pass 'null'. But i don't know why you'd do that.

Comment: I get the system message from my provider (I receive the broadcast "SMS delivered" from the example above), not a seperate sms and a i think some providers may charge this notification.  That is why i want to prevent this deliveryIntent.

Comment: From my experience, they don't charge it. Why should they, almost every mobile device has that function.

Comment: I can confirm they charge for it, 0,15€ in Italy (even with 1000 free sms /month, still charged). Does passing null effect it?